# When can you directly multiply into a series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Searched around but havent found a hard answer. Under what circumstances (and optimally also why) can you multiply a known taylor series by another element without having to recalculate the taylor series.

For example

I know the Maclaurin series approximation for $\mathrm{e}^x$ is
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$

for $x^5 \mathrm{e}^x$ I can simply combine the terms in the series approximation and get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^5 x^n}{n!}$ which equals $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+5}}{n!}$

However if I go the other way and first calculate the series approximation for $x^5$ I cannot just multiply in $\mathrm{e}^x$
as that would give me the original equation and not the same approximation.

Similarly, it does not work and you have to work out the long way (unless I am mistaken) for something like $\mathrm{e}^x \sin x$ or for $\frac{\sin x}{1-x}$ . In the first case you can't work out one side and multiply by the other and in the second you can't find the power series of  $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and multiply it by $\sin x$.

Edit: to be more clear what I am asking is why can I sometimes multiply the second element term directly and other times it doesn't work ie. $\sin x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$ is not
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \cdot x^{n}}{n!}$.

Would appreciate any guidance (and even more so if its intuitive!)

Comment: What do you mean by the series approximation for $x^5$?  The Maclaurin series is the function itself (one term $x^5$).

Comment: If your power series involves monomials of the form $x^k$, then yes, you can multiply your series expression $f(x)\sim \sum \frac{x^n}{n!} $ by $x^p$ and obtain $x^p f(x) \sim \sum \frac{x^{n+p}}{n!}$.

Comment: All of the multiplications you described are valid; it's just that only some of them result in power series rather than some other kind of series.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @mjw , I mean what you wrote for $\mathrm{x}^5$. Im essentially asking why I dont get the same result when I find the maclaurin series for $\mathrm{e}^x$ and then simply multiply the monomial into it vs find the maclaurin series for the monomial and then just straight multiply the $\mathrm{e}^x$ into it.

Comment: And why I cant do that for either direction of $\mathrm{e}^x sinx$. (I played around and got the same result as you answered that I can term by term multiply the sinx/(1-x) but I am pretty sure I cant do that for $\mathrm{e}^x sinx$

Comment: You could multiply the series $e^x$ by the series for $\sin x$.  Why not?  Just do it carefully!  (Use different variable names for the indices of each series and multiply term-by term).

Comment: Can I? I understand I can do it term by term as in multiplying out everything but my question is about directly multiplying into the summation and unless im wrong Im pretty sure $sinx \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{x}^{n}}{n!}$ is not
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{sinx \mathrm{x}^{n}}{n!}$

Comment: Are $\mathrm{x}$ and $x$ the same? Why are you using this ugly $\mathrm{x}$? By the way those two series are the same.

Comment: @Gary yes they are, apologies

Comment: "$\sin x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$ is not
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \cdot x^{n}}{n!}$" sure it is; it's just that neither of them is a Taylor series in the variable $x$

Comment: I think you want to use the _convolution_ of the coefficients of the two power series to get the coefficients of the product of the two series. It is the same thing with multiplying two polynomials.

Comment: @JBL Can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: I mean that $\sin(x) \cdot \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n \cdot \sin(x)}{n!}$ is a true statement.  Neither side of the equation is the Taylor series of the function $\sin(x) \cdot e^x$ (because neither side has the right form to be a Taylor series), but they're still equal.  When you do it with $x^5$ instead of $\sin(x)$ it happens that you get a Taylor series on one side by a lucky coincidence, but that's separate from the fact that you can distribute the factor into the sum.

Comment: Stop thinking about Taylor series for a minute and just think about polynomials: $x \cdot (17 + 3x + 2x^2) = x + 3x^2 + 2x^3$.  Also $(2x - 3) \cdot (17 + 3x + 2x^2) = (2x - 3)\cdot 17 + (2x -3 ) \cdot 3x + (2x - 3) \cdot 2x^2$.  The first one happens to be in a nice form because the factor you multiplied by was very simple; in the second one, the factor you multiplied by isn't as simple, but you could expand it out and put it in the same nice form if you wanted.

Comment: @JBL thanks that makes sense

Comment: Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n$ is associated with the sequence
$$\sum^1_{n=1}a_n,\sum^2_{n=1}a_n,\dots,\sum^k_{n=1}a_n,\dots$$
and is defined to be the limit of this sequence. For any convergent sequence $A_1,A_2,\dots$ it holds that
$$A\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}(A_n)^k_{n=1}=\lim_{k\to\infty}(A\cdot A_n)^k_{n=1}$$
as long as $A$ is independent of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1} x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!},$$

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k, \quad (|x|<1).$$

You can multiply these series (where $|x|<1$) term-by-term.